# Why did Jules have to give Ringo $1,500?

Tags: pulp-fiction

In one of the more famous Pulp Fiction scenes, Jules and Vincent are eating at a diner when Ringo and Honey Bunny decide to rob it.  Their attempt doesn't go well.

At one point, Jules tells Ringo to open up his wallet and take out $1,500.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PeyiU3uWJ8&t=1m22s

> *Now, I ain't giving it to him, Vincent.  I'm buying something for my money.  Wanna know what I'm buying, Ringo?*
>
> "What?"
>
> *"Your life.  **I'm giving you that money so I don't have to kill yo' ass.**"*

What does giving Ringo $1,500 have to do with not killing him?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By this point in the narrative, Jules had already decided that he was going to change his life - he no longer wanted to be a killer for hire. The affair with the bullets missing him in Marvin's apartment had convinced him that God had a higher purpose for him, and by allowing Ringo to take what he needed, Jules was ensuring that he wouldn't have to kill him for attempting to rob him.

This was the first step towards Jules' new life.

He was not only buying/saving Ringo's life, but also his own.

Comment: I see, so he meant "You're not taking the money from me, I'm giving it to you, because if you took it from me I would kill you."

Comment: Essentially, yes. And Jules doesn't want to kill any more.